# Problema con headers en php

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tengo un problema con los headers en mi formulario, ya que el formulario al ser enviado y al llegar a mi correo aparece como *user545412* y seguido del correo del proveedor del hosting y no del remitente, y si le añado el punto al header de *MIME-Version* al ser enviado llega el correo del remitente pero con un *1.0* al principio, lo que necesito es que simplemente me llegue el correo del remitente.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

```js
$headers ='From: '.$_POST['mail'];
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Los sitios de hosting pueden sobreescribir el valor de `From` ya que de otra manera el correo seria rechazado como spam (el usuario/dominio que envia es distinto al usuario en el correo).

Lo ideal es colocar en el campo `From:` el correo usado para autenticarse en phpmailer (usando SMTP) con el que se envia el correo, o un correo real registrado en el dominio del proveedor de hosting (ej: notificaciones@tudominio.com) .

No se puede usar `From:` con una direccion no reconocida por el servidor de envio.
Si deseas que el correo tenga una direccion de respuesta puedes agregar el encabezado `Reply-to`:

```
$mail->AddReplyTo('replyto@email.com', 'Reply to name');
```